# Capturing URL parameters from facebook tab URL

Tags: php, facebook

I need to capture the URL parameters from my facebook tab URL, i.e.

https://www.facebook.com/name/app_MYID?v=app_MYID&app_data=%7Bid%3A1%7D

The app_data parameter value is {id:1} .

My php looks like this

```
require 'fb/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'my_app_id',
  'secret' => 'my_secret',
  'cookie' => true
));
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$appData = array();
if (!empty($signedRequest) && !empty($signedRequest['app_data'])) {
  $appData = json_decode($signedRequest['app_data'], true);
}
```

The entry $signedRequest['app_data'] is never set. And there are no FB errors anywhere, all the other entries of $signedRequest like $signedRequest['code'] look ok.

My app is in sandbox mode. There are no redirects going on that cause the parameters to get lost.

What can I do?

Here is my dump of signedRequest:

```
 array(4) { ["algorithm"]=> string(11) "HMAC-SHA256" ["code"]=> string(344) "AQCPnmrVunEJ3D4qbwm2PrulMCJrd14iLfK6MwNmA8FzdaIGwlO4OmlvaYiNss0BJjIIjV5P5P2Oq4JrK71qbB-MBi8jcb26TabckkvJF5lGhyGpgRv5BHY_-YAOnqch1CMAKMwZCYcXIZP6CjSdXvoE-ZkDe_QhIKGi8fdNRFQHrwxNSr4oDKtwqNxKCLPJ96nQOlNrw_GxE5ARamR26ge9hmSnKY6cPdA9C0IMTDnufXJoYOluuFt53_Vu59Jqv33tWmP6gz-zV9kuJ8MIvXkfFCpxlzAh2Wgr_cyx7OumxCNv5NDvzeYNhHDOg1MrP2zwxI9ex_YG6A9_eNf_UASy" ["issued_at"]=> int(1374715498) ["user_id"]=> string(15) "100004071391531" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration issue. The target URL was missing the trailing "/". What a waste of time!